# Why am I facing a delay while calling the autoDiscoverUrl method of the Exchange Web Service API?

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, autodiscovery

I am using a Java Exchange Web Service API to connect to a mailbox on `office365.com`

Following is the code snippet that I have written to authenticate and establish a connection via auto-discovery:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(exchangeUserName,Password,exchangeDomainName);
service.setCredentials(credentials);  
service.autodiscoverUrl(fromAddress);
```

Here, I have noticed that the `autodiscoverUrl()` method is taking 15-20 minutes to discover and set the URL. Why is there a delay in this and how do I debug or address this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to test the autodiscover retrieval using the Remote Connectivity Analyzer tool: https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/